# 600B | Codeforces | Queries about less or equal elements

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

Here's the question: [Link](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/600/B)

My code is below:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
#define output(x) cout << x << endl
#define ll long long

ll binarySearch(vector<ll> vec, ll num, ll n) {
    ll left = 0;
    ll right = n-1;
    ll mid = 0;

    while (left <= right) {
        mid = (left+right)/2;

        if (left == right) {
            break;
        }

        if (vec[mid] <= num) {
            left = mid+1;
        }
        else {
            right = mid;
        }
    }

    if (vec[mid] <= num) {
        return mid+1;
    }

    return mid;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{ 
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    ll a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    vector<ll> avec(a);

    for (auto &it: avec) {
        cin >> it;
    }

    sort(avec.begin(), avec.end());

    ll curr;
    map<ll, ll> answers;

    while (b--) {
        cin >> curr;

        if (answers[curr] != 0) {
            cout << answers[curr] << " ";
        }
        else {
            ll ans = binarySearch(avec, curr, a);
            answers[curr] = ans;

            cout << ans << " "; 
        }

    }

    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't pass the time limits. However, when I use the internal function `upper_bound` instead of calling my `binarySearch`, it passes
`upper_bound` is called as below

```
cout << (upper_bound(avec.begin(), avec.end(), curr) - avec.begin()) << " ";
```

Is there a way to submit this question successfully without needing to use internal function? Can the binary search be more optimised?

Comment: A little gain: pass `vec` by reference to `binary_search`

Comment: that was the problem, it got accepted - if you wish, please post your comment as an answer and I will accept. @Damien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, `ll binarySearch(vector<ll> vec, ll num, ll n) {`, you pass the vector `vec`by copy.

The complexity of the copy is O(n). So, even if the algorithm is O(logn), the global complexity of the function is still O(n).

By making the call by reference:

```
ll binarySearch(vector<ll> &vec, ll num, ll n) {
```

The call by itself costs O(1) and the global complexity of the function remains O(logn).